# magento homepage 404 status

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-404

OK...I am going crazy...

I have a Magento store in a /store/ directory. The homepage displays fine and users are able to make purchases, but to bots it's showing a 404 status code.

So /store/ and /store/index.php are both 404 header responses but I can navigate to those pages and browse the website from there. I've never seen this before.....blah

When I crawl the site with Xenu from the http://www.mywebsite.com/store/ URL it says it's 404 and the title shows, "redir" so I am assuming there is some redirect somewhere that I am missing(?)....

Any help is appreciated...I may need to explain this better so if so, I will gladly :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: appreciated...but no...it's not being blocked it's returning a 404 status response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate all the help!

Somehow, changing the CMS page assigned as the homepage fixed the problem. The original homepage was calling some entity that returned a 404 error in turn giving a 404 error for the entire page.

Really not sure what happened...but like I said, changing the CMS homepage solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried browsing your site with browser and a user agent switcher? There are examples of Magento being unable to build collections when the user agent is one of the bots which is explicitly left out of the log information.

Comment: Interesting...didn't try that but going to just to see what happens, thanks!